# CodeIgniter Joins not working on select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Actually I am trying to return a specific row that contains data in other two tables, I am using CodeIgniter as framework, and I have no idea what is wrong :/

What I noticed it is showing only data from (usuarios), nothing from (filiais) or (func_professores)... here is my function from model file, tried everything I found on Stack already, nothing seems to work, if anyone can gimme a hand I will be grateful as I aint that good with sql and queries.

```
    function ver_usuario($user_id){
    $this->db->where('usuarios.id = "'.$user_id.'"'); // 1 = Administrador, 3 = Recepcionista, 4 = Professores/Personal Trainers, 5 = Gerente
    $this->db->select('usuarios.id, usuarios.email, usuarios.nome, usuarios.sobrenome, usuarios.cpf, usuarios.sexo, usuarios.data_nascimento, usuarios.telefone, usuarios.celular, usuarios.endereco, usuarios.numero, usuarios.cep, usuarios.bairro, usuarios.cidade, usuarios.estado, usuarios.filial, usuarios.usuario_tipo, usuarios.data_cadastro, filiais.filial_nome, func_professores.fp_email, func_professores.fp_cpf, func_professores.fp_formacao, func_professores.fp_instituicao, func_professores.fp_cref, func_professores.fp_telefone, func_professores.fp_endereco, func_professores.fp_bairro, func_professores.fp_cidade, func_professores.fp_estado');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    $this->db->join('filiais', 'usuarios.filial = filiais.filial_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('func_professores', 'usuarios.cpf = func_professores.fp_cpf', 'left');
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

I tried removing 'left' from joins, putting one 'left' and the other one 'right'.. removing it from both.. nothing worked.

Thank you.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: add the image of your tables for writting a proper query

Comment: Thanks guys, it is working fine now.. haven't edited nothing neither applied any change suggested by other users here.

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
$this->db->select('usuarios.id, usuarios.email, usuarios.nome, usuarios.sobrenome, usuarios.cpf, usuarios.sexo, usuarios.data_nascimento, usuarios.telefone, usuarios.celular, usuarios.endereco, usuarios.numero, usuarios.cep, usuarios.bairro, usuarios.cidade, usuarios.estado, usuarios.filial, usuarios.usuario_tipo, usuarios.data_cadastro, filiais.filial_nome, func_professores.fp_email, func_professores.fp_cpf, func_professores.fp_formacao, func_professores.fp_instituicao, func_professores.fp_cref, func_professores.fp_telefone, func_professores.fp_endereco, func_professores.fp_bairro, func_professores.fp_cidade, func_professores.fp_estado');
$this->db->from('usuarios');
$this->db->join('filiais', 'usuarios.filial = filiais.filial_id');
$this->db->join('func_professores', 'usuarios.cpf = func_professores.fp_cpf');
$this->db->where('usuarios.id', $user_id);
return $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thank you too man, but my query suddently worked fine today when I started to work in the code again, no idea what happened I also didn't edited nothing else, so dunno what happened but things are working now.. thank you again for spending your time trying to help me, really appreciated man!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function ver_usuario($user_id){
   $this->db->select('usuarios.id, usuarios.email, usuarios.nome, usuarios.sobrenome, usuarios.cpf, usuarios.sexo, usuarios.data_nascimento, usuarios.telefone, usuarios.celular, usuarios.endereco, usuarios.numero, usuarios.cep, usuarios.bairro, usuarios.cidade, usuarios.estado, usuarios.filial, usuarios.usuario_tipo, usuarios.data_cadastro, filiais.filial_nome, func_professores.fp_email, func_professores.fp_cpf, func_professores.fp_formacao, func_professores.fp_instituicao, func_professores.fp_cref, func_professores.fp_telefone, func_professores.fp_endereco, func_professores.fp_bairro, func_professores.fp_cidade, func_professores.fp_estado');
   $this->db->where('usuarios.id', $user_id);
   $this->db->from('usuarios');       
   $this->db->join('filiais', 'usuarios.filial = filiais.filial_id');
   $this->db->join('func_professores', 'usuarios.cpf = func_professores.fp_cpf');
   return $this->db->get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my query suddently worked fine today when I started to work in the code again, no idea what happened I also didn't edited nothing else, so dunno what happened but things are working now.. thank you again for spending your time trying to help me, really appreciated man!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function ver_usuario($user_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('usuarios.id, usuarios.email, usuarios.nome, usuarios.sobrenome, usuarios.cpf, usuarios.sexo, usuarios.data_nascimento, usuarios.telefone, usuarios.celular, usuarios.endereco, usuarios.numero, usuarios.cep, usuarios.bairro, usuarios.cidade, usuarios.estado, usuarios.filial, usuarios.usuario_tipo, usuarios.data_cadastro, filiais.filial_nome, func_professores.fp_email, func_professores.fp_cpf, func_professores.fp_formacao, func_professores.fp_instituicao, func_professores.fp_cref, func_professores.fp_telefone, func_professores.fp_endereco, func_professores.fp_bairro, func_professores.fp_cidade, func_professores.fp_estado');
        $this->db->from('usuarios');
        $this->db->join('filiais', 'usuarios.filial = filiais.filial_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('func_professores', 'usuarios.cpf = func_professores.fp_cpf', 'left');
        $this->db->where('usuarios.id',$user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
            if($query->num_rows() != 0)
            {
                return $query->result_array();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
```

You are care about if any table have same column name and that is used in select, then use that column name with table name and use the **as** keyword too

(ie. if 2 tables have same field names: id, we can avoid ambiguity among these by using **table1.id as id1** and **table2.id as id2**)

Comment: Your comment should be outside of the code block. Additionally it's quite unclear what you're trying to say. I've attempted to edit your comment in the last line, but got stuck. Please update so that it makes sense please.